# Does dplyr `rowwise()` group in the same way `group_by()` groups?

Tags: r, dplyr, row, grouping, rowwise

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% is_grouped_df()
#> [1] TRUE
```

I can group a data frame by a variable and confirm if it is grouped using the `is_grouped_df()` function (shown above).

I can run the same analysis on the dplyr `rowwise()` function and it appears that `rowwise()` does not group data sets by row. I have a question and a reading of the help page (`?rowwise`) does not clearly answer the question for me.

> **Group input by rows**
>
> Description: rowwise() allows you to compute on a data frame a row-at-a-time. This is most useful when a vectorised function doesn't exist.
>
> A row-wise tibble maintains its row-wise status until explicitly removed by group_by(), ungroup(), or as_tibble().

*My question*: After calling the `rowwise()` function do I need to call the `ungroup()` function later in my pipe to ungroup my data set? Or is this done by default? The following pipe suggests that a pipe containing `rowwise()` is not grouped:

```
mtcars %>% rowwise() %>% is_grouped_df()
#> [1] FALSE
```

This sentence is confusing me, "*A row-wise tibble maintains its row-wise status until explicitly removed by... ungroup()...*". Why would I need to `ungroup()` a tibble that is already ungrouped?

Comment: What's the goal of the analysis?

Comment: @rpolicastro trying to determine if I need to call `ungroup()` after calling `rowwise()` in a pipe. This is assuming you want an ungrouped data set at the end of your pipe (which I do).

Comment: It is interesting.  I think it could be a bug, but if you check the `str(mtcars %>% group_by_all)` and `str(mtcars %>% rowwise())`, the group attributes for the variables are not seen in `rowwise`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting observation. This might be a bug of `is_grouped_df` unless it's somehow a feature that I don't know about. But I DO think it's important to `ungroup` considering the testing done below (see comments):

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% select(1:3) %>% rowwise() %>% head(2)
#> Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#> Groups: <by row>
##### ^ THIS DOES HAVE A GROUP ####
#> 
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>     mpg   cyl  disp
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    21     6   160
#> 2    21     6   160

mtcars %>% select(1:3) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(n()) %>% head(2)
#> Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>     mpg   cyl  disp `n()`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1    21     6   160     1
#> 2    21     6   160     1
mtcars %>% select(1:3) %>% mutate(n()) %>% head(2)                                              
#>   mpg cyl disp n()
#> 1  21   6  160  32
#> 2  21   6  160  32

##### ^ THIS IS EXPECTED AND THE n BEHAVES DIFFERENTLY WHEN THE ROWWISE() IS APPLIED ####

##### IF WE WANT TO RESTORE "NORMAL" BEHAVIOR, IT'S PROBABLY WISE TO UNGROUP IN ORDER TO LOSE THE ROWWISE OPERATIONS #####
mtcars %>% select(1:3) %>% rowwise() %>% ungroup %>% mutate(n()) %>% head(2)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>     mpg   cyl  disp `n()`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1    21     6   160    32
#> 2    21     6   160    32

## ^ NORMAL AFTER UNGROUP
```